# I set a variable, but the value is lost after the function exits

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if a variable has being set within an if/else statement.

If it hasn't been set, I want to add a node to the DOM, but if it has been set, I want to update the node.

The problem is that the "else" case never seems to fire.

What have I missed?

```
function (response) {
    if (typeof outputmessage === 'undefined') {
        var outputmessage = document.createElement("p");
        outputmessage.innerHTML = response;
        TA.parentNode.insertBefore(outputmessage, TA.nextSibling);
    } else {
        outputmessage.innerHTML = response;
    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be a scope issue, but where are you using this code (so that we can suggest an alternative)?

Comment: Its just a small ajax script for a contact form which submits to a php file, this is handling the success function.

Comment: as suggested where is the var outputmessage being set as if its outside your scope might mean you need to pass it to the function function (response, outputmessage) also try 'undefined' without the quotes

Comment: Where does `outputmessage` get defined other than in this function?

Comment: It doesnt thanks for pointing out the scope issues, I moved var outputmessage outside the function and then delcared it once inside and all is now good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the `outputmessage` variable outside of the function scope, because it is effectively being reset each time the function is called:

```
var outputmessage;

function (response) {
    if (typeof outputmessage === 'undefined') {
        outputmessage = document.createElement("p");
        outputmessage.innerHTML = response;
        TA.parentNode.insertBefore(outputmessage, TA.nextSibling);
    } else {
        outputmessage.innerHTML = response;
    }
}
```

---

Just to expand on the problem, due to [variable hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) your original code was effectively equivalent to the following, which shows why `outputmessage` would always evaluate to undefined:

```
function (response) {
    var outputmessage;
    if (typeof outputmessage === 'undefined') {
        outputmessage = document.createElement("p");
    //...
}
```

Comment: The solution is always so obvious when in your hands. Thanks